# why form data not passing?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I tried to make document for upload image in php but the document getiamge.php not accepting the form data and also giving warning.

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Image Upload</title>
    <script>

        function Insert() 
    {
        var image= document.getElementById("image").value;

        var name= document.getElementById("name").value;





    if (image == ""  && name == "") 
    {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Please Fill The Fields";
        return;
    }
        else if (image == "" || name == "") 
            {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Please Fill The Form Correctly.";
                return;
            }
        else
        { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else 
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            {
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };


        xmlhttp.open("POST","getimage.php?name="+name+"&image="+image,true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");    
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }



    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="image">
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="button" value="Upload" onClick="Insert()">
    <h6 id="message">yyys</h6>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**getimage.php**

```
<?php
include("2nd.php");

$a=$_POST['image'];
$name=$_POST['name'];

$path="images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']); 

$image=base64_encode($a);
$query="INSERT INTO images(image,name) VALUES ('".$image."','".$name."')";

$insert=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if($insert)
{
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['name']))
    {

    echo "Uploaded Successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Not Uploaded successfully";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Not Inserted";
}
?>
```

**And the warnings are these**

Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Undefined index: image in D:\xampp\htdocs\image\getimage.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\xampp\htdocs\image\getimage.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: image in D:\xampp\htdocs\image\getimage.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: image in D:\xampp\htdocs\image\getimage.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: image in D:\xampp\htdocs\image\getimage.php on line 17
Not Uploaded successfully

Comment: where is action in <form enctype="multipart/form-data"> ?

Comment: I used the action in form but warnings are still coming.

Comment: refer https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: remove enctype="multipart/form-data" if you are not going to upload more than 1 image

Comment: That is not how to upload using ajax. The value of the input is only the name of the file...not the file itself.  There are lots of resources on the web for how to do it. The other comments above are irrelevant

Comment: Can you tell me how to correct the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

`Notice: Undefined index: image` error is coming because you are sending image in POST data, so it will come in `$_POST['image']` to receive in `$_FILES['image']['name']` you have to use `FormData()` like as below:

'

```
    function Insert() 
{
    var image= document.getElementById("image").files[0];

    var name= document.getElementById("name").value;

if (image == ""  && name == "") 
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Please Fill The Fields";
    return;
}
    else if (image == "" || name == "") 
        {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="Please Fill The Form Correctly.";
            return;
        }
    else
    { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else 
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };


     xmlhttp.open("POST","getimage.php",true);
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");  
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append("image", image);
     formData.append("name", name);
     xmlhttp.send(formData);
    }
}
</script>'
```